# In Mojolicious, how do I display my session's data?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I expect this to be marked as a dup, but I've searched and searched and can't find any questions that are similar, much less the answer. When a Mojolicious template has an error, you get a page that shows all of the session data.

[image: Example of desired output]

For debugging, I created a "dump" page that contains a deliberate error, but that seems to be a mite inefficient. Is there a simple way (like an already defined helper) to append the same well-formatted information to a page that I'm debugging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to load Data::Dumper for that. One of the built-in helpers *is* Data::Dumper.

```
% if ($debug_mode) { dumper $session; }
```

or specific values:

```
% if ($debug_mode) { dumper $session->some_value; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than throwing an error, you could call `render_exception` (which is what throwing an error does), but even that isn't the best idea. You should try using tempire's excellent [Mojolicious::Plugin::ConsoleLogger](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious%3a%3aPlugin%3a%3aConsoleLogger) which will send all the information you could ever want to your browser's javascript console.

Comment: And I'll give you a +1, but again, I was hoping to find a helper that I could include on a page to dump everything right there.

Comment: If you want to see the page you are rendering (i.e. not the 500 page you show above) how would you also see the debug output? Where would it go? This is what the console is for. If you want to actually render the information like the 500 screen, you could copy the code from the [exception template](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/blob/master/lib/Mojolicious/templates/exception.development.html.ep), but no there is no one-shot helper for what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean a page like an HTML template? You can just insert it into an HTML comment anywhere on any template:

```
% if ($debug_mode) {
%    my $session_dump = Data::Dumper::Dumper($self->session);
<!--  session data is: <%= $session_dump %> -->
% }
```

Then view the page source when you want to inspect the session data.

Comment: I'll give this a +1, because I'm already doing something similar in my pages: <pre><%= dumper $self %></pre> What I want, however, is to easily produce the nicely formatted output that I've now added to my original question.